# Can't figure out how to multiply polynomials with only x multiplications of large numbers

Tags: polynomials

I'm really lost with this, there was an example of how to do a similar question in my notes with evaluating the polynomial created by the product of the first and second polynomial at n+1 values

[Here's the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ba9C.png)

Comment: Horner's method seems related but not the same.

Comment: This seems amenable to the basic idea in [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Basic_step) which achieves the work of 4 multiplications with only 3.  Are you familiar with it?  Naively, this idea looks like it leads to 19 multiplications rather than 16, but it is a noticeable improvement over the brute-force 25.

Comment: @ErickWong I think I do a very basic amount, could you explain a bit how you get it to 19 multiplications?

Comment: @FrankBilliams It takes 9 multiplications to brute-force the coefficients which contain $a_0$ and $b_0$.  For the remaining higher-degree coefficients, we are essentially multiplying two dense polynomials of degree $3$.  These have four terms each ($2\cdot 2$), so we should be able to Karatsuba recursively to do them in $3\cdot 3 = 9$ multiplications, for a total of 18.